# Angular renders elements but doesn't display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm receiving data from the resource factory, but when I try to output this it renders elements, but remains empty. It's strange because I can see it resolved in the console log.

**Controller**

```
dichotomy.controller('WorkplaceOverview', ['$scope', 'WorkPlace', function ($scope, WorkPlace) {
$scope.workplaces = WorkPlace.all({get_all:1}).$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.workplaces = response;
         console.log($scope.workplaces);
    });
}]);
```

**Factory**

```
    dichotomy.factory('WorkPlace', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/create_workplace/:id/:get_all/', {}, {
        all: {method: "GET", isArray: true, params: {get_all: '@get_all'}},
        get: {method: "GET", isArray: false, params: {id: '@id'}},
        update: {method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the value twice (second time to a promise).

Try

```
dichotomy.controller('WorkplaceOverview', ['$scope', 'WorkPlace', function ($scope, WorkPlace) {
  WorkPlace.all({get_all:1}).$promise.then(function (response) {
      $scope.workplaces = response;
      console.log($scope.workplaces);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: If the `console.log` outputs the correct info you are setting the value somewhere else.

Comment: Try inserting a `{{ workplaces }}` tag in your HTML (inside the controller) and see if it renders anything.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I found a problem. I've made a typo in ng-repeat that i use to render data in view.

Comment: I was going to ask for your view code... why people post half the relevant stuff these days... 